# Number Of Records Affected With This Statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

How can I get the number of records affected by this statement:

```
select * from x_table where column1 = 5
```

I thought `ExecuteNonQuery` is what I need but it returned -1. I expected 2 because I have two records with `column1 = 5` in my table. How do I get the correct count?

Comment: How you execute this query? The c# code I mean

Comment: Why would you use `ExecuteNonQuery` to run a `SELECT`? Why not use `ExecuteScalar` and actually return the count, e.g. `SELECT c = COUNT(*)...WHERE...`?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() is for executing something that is not a query; you are trying to execute a query, are you not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `ExecuteNonQuery` - but this is a query! No rows are *affected* by your statement because it's just a query. You need to put the counting part into the query, like this:

```
select count(*) from x_table where column1 = 5
```

And then the simplest way of getting the result is to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

```
int count = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

You *could* just execute it as a reader and get the sole result, but `ExecuteScalar` is simpler.

Answer (score 7):

```
select count(*) from x_table where column1=5
```

Execute it as a normal query. The result will be a single row with a single column containing the number of matching records.

Comment: +1.  Or you can call it using ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteReader`. `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete operation, not select.

Using `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM X_TABLE WHERE COLUMN1=5` is fine, but execute it as
`int rows = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());`

Answer (score 1):

from a SQL point of view, this is all you'd need

```
select count(*) from x_table where column1=5
```

I'm not sure if there's a shortcut using Linq or something though.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify as to why you got -1.

[From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.